# how to half fill the diamond box with some color and text within it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

here i have taken an image and i want to half fill the image with some color and text within it and make it appear only on hover?

this is the image b4 hovering!

[image]

this is the image after hovering

[image]

html:

```
 <div class="product_img">
  <img src=""/>

    <div class="product_des">
     <div class="product_des_content">
      <p><span>Trade Name :</span> White Wholes</p>
      <p><span>Colour/Characteristics :</span> White/pale ivory/light ash. Characteristic shape</p>     
    </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

css:

```
  <style>
   .product_img{width:32%;float:left;margin:6px;height:248px;border:1px solid #000; position: relative;-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);}
 .product_img img{width:100%;}
 .product_img ul {width:100%;background:#E64A43;float:left;}
 .product_img ul li{color:#fff;width:49%;float:left;text-align:center;border-right:1px solid #000;list-style:none;font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';}
.product_img ul li:last-child{border-right:none;}
 .product_des{color: #fff; background:#000; visibility: hidden;transition:1s;opacity: 0;width:100%;float:left;height:248px;float:left; position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;}
.product_des_content{float:left;margin:75px 0 0 0;}
 .product_des p{text-align:center;width:100%;font-family: 'open_sanslight';font-size:15px;}
.product_des p span{font-weight:bold;}
.product_img:hover .product_des {visibility: visible;opacity:0.75;}
</style>
```

Comment: can you share  your codes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Anyway, without your code, try something like this:*

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/c878296c4c7f43b8bbb285acb73c0e6c.png');
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    top: -54px;
    left: -54px;
}

div::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 482px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -200px;
    left: 0;
    transition: .3s all ease;
}

div:hover::after {
bottom: 0;  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: can we take background image instead of that red background?

Comment: Answer updated. you can do this with `after` or `before` or `img` element, because of `rotate` you can not use background for `div` and you need to use other element for background.

Comment: how about adding some text on hover along with the current output? like shown in the image that i uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Check with below code it may help to develop the same.

```css
div#UserInfo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:lightgray;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

div#UserInfo::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 482px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0, .5);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -200px;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}
div#UserInfo:hover::after {
  bottom: 0;  
}

.userImg{
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.userDtls{
  transform: rotate(315deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 85px;
  display: none;
  transition: 50s all ease;
  text-align : center;
}

.userName{
  text-transform : uppercase;
  
}

#UserInfo:hover .userDtls{
  display: block;
  color : white;
  z-index : 999;
}
```

```html
<div Id="UserInfo">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/PRACTIKA/256/user.png" class="userImg"/>
  <div class="userDtls">
  <span class="userName">Charlie </span><br>
  <span>UI Designer</span>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an full css-solution, or is the regular/simple solution alright for your?

I would use two different images for this and put them in one sprite-image. The first image is used to show the normal state, the second one is used to fill the diamond.

More information about sprite-images (and an example) can be found on W3schools:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav

Does this answer your question?
If you post some code, I can show you how it works.

Comment: You should only post things as answer for which you are sure..by posting links won't help op as answer.. try to post them as comment.. Thanx